# I just downloaded android studio and my instructor me to use a new directory . However, that is not an option on this versions

Tags: android, android-studio

I know this is a simple question, but I can't find an answer. This is my first time using android. The only option there is android resource directory. Is there another similar option I use  for this version?

Comment: What kind of directory?

Comment: I am supposed to create an jniLibs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a plain `directory`, switch to `project files` then right click where you want the `directory` then go to `new` then `directory`. Here is a picture:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying create a directory in the java folder, creating a new package will create a new directory in the filesystem. Right click where you want to create in the Project tree and select New->Package.

Comment: By default they are the same thing, but not always. In Java, all of the files contained in the same directory are by default added to the same, nameless package. So in Android Studio, creating a new (unnamed) package will necessitate a new directory being created to contain it. However, any number of named packages can also be created in an existing directory by writing `package myPackage;` at the top of each file. Check out [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/createpkgs.html) and the surrounding pages for more info.